# App bundle is causing Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, gradle, android-app-bundle

I switched from APK to app bundle and i get the following error from crashlitics:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800b5
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1561)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:146)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:425)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:129)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:211)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:186)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:197)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:479)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1160)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:234)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:292)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1047)
       at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1074)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1410)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1648)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:140)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5856)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

in My R.java:

```
public static int design_fab_size_mini = 0x7f0800b5;
```

Any ideas on what happened and how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it happens in Android App Bundle after apk has been sideloaded to different devices, it is normal, please see in docs
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

> Because app installs may require downloading more than one APK (such
>   the base APK and a few of its configuration APKs), you should be
>   careful when manually transferring your app’s APKs onto a device (also
>   known as sideloading). Otherwise, your app may experience runtime
>   issues due to missing code and resources.

Comment: I'll add as a note that it only happens when the app has been _incorrectly_ sidelodaded, i.e. only the base APK was installed on the device without the config APKs.